# Two async AJAX calls returns same result

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)calls and I am calling them `async`:

```
xmlhttpPostInstagram2('firsturl');
xmlhttpPostInstagram3('secondurl');
```

The problem is I am getting the same results from both calls. If I change `async` to sync, I am getting two different results which is the expected one. Can any one point what is messing up the ajax `async` call?

I do not want to use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)answer would be appreciated.

```
function xmlhttpPostInstagram2(strURL) {
  var originalValue = ""
  var xmlHttpReq = false;

  var self = this;
  // Mozilla/Safari
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  // IE
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
  self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

      var temp2 = document.getElementById('sidebartag');
      temp2.innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText; // child is the fetched string from ajax call in your case
    }

  }
  self.xmlHttpReq.send();
}
```

and

```
function xmlhttpPostInstagram3(strURL) {
  var originalValue = ""
  var xmlHttpReq = false;

  var self = this;
  // Mozilla/Safari
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  // IE
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
  self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

      var temp2 = document.getElementById('sidebartag1');
      temp2.innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText; // child is the fetched string from ajax call in your case
    }

  }
  self.xmlHttpReq.send();
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is a scoping issue. Check my answer and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation without using jQuery.**

In your case:

You're calling simultaneously to these functions: `xmlhttpPostInstagram2('firsturl');` `xmlhttpPostInstagram3('secondurl');` When you run the first function `xmlhttpPostInstagram2`, you initialize the `XMLHttpRequest` object and simultaneously, in the second function `xmlhttpPostInstagram3` you overwrite the `XMLHttpRequest` object because the first request is not completed.

You might try declaring independently an instance of `XMLHttpRequest` in each function. Something like this:

```
function xmlhttpPostInstagram2(strURL) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open("POST", strURL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var temp2 = document.getElementById("sidebartag");
            obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            temp2.innerHTML = obj.name;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

And:

```
function xmlhttpPostInstagram3(strURL) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open("POST", strURL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var temp2 = document.getElementById("sidebartag1");
            obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            temp2.innerHTML = obj.name;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Then, you can run these functions simultaneously properly:

```
 xmlhttpPostInstagram2("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London");
 xmlhttpPostInstagram3("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=UK");
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/k1rcb0cw/)</kbd>

Comment: call back is already implemented. Please see the event : onreadystatechange

Comment: But, you're calling simultaneously to these functions: xmlhttpPostInstagram2('firsturl');
xmlhttpPostInstagram3('secondurl');

When you run the first function «xmlhttpPostInstagram2», you initialize the XMLHttpRequest object and simultaneously, in the second function «xmlhttpPostInstagram3» you overwrite the XMLHttpRequest object because the first request is not completed.

Comment: Then i will have two different XMLHttpRequest objects and see it that works.

Comment: and it worked. I instanced a different XMLHttpRequest for each functions and it worked.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your answer to suit this, I will accept as an answer because I have clearly stated in my question that i donot need a jquery solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to scope. You have the line:

```
var self = this;
```

In the scope of the function (from what I can tell from the code you have provided), `this` refers to the `window`. Therefore `self` is equal to `window`.
To check this add a `console.log(self)` after the self declaration statement and check the result in your browser dev tools.

```
var self = this;
console.log(self); // Logs Window object to console.
```

You are then running the following statement:

```
self.xmlHttpReq = new ...
```

When you are doing this, the variable reference of `xmlHttpReq` refers to the same variable in both of your functions (i.e. `window.xmlHttpReq`). This variable is being overwritten when you make the second function call, which would explain why it would appear that you are getting the same result from both function calls.

To fix this you can declare `xmlHttp` as a local variable within the scope of the function:

```
function xmlhttpPostInstagram2(){
  var xmlHttpReq;

  // Mozilla/Safari
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  // IE
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  //etc...
}
```